# Fedora: whole-disk MD, LUKS, and partitions

Tags: partitioning, fedora, mdadm, luks

Fedora pre 30.

Months ago, I set up an entire 5TB drive as a single-device RAID1 `md` volume (`md100`), LUKS-encrypted it with `cryptsetup`, and created partitions on it.

However, coming back to it now, I can't get the partitions to show up as anything mountable.

```bsh
# mdadm -A --scan

# cryptsetup open /dev/md100 md100
Enter passphrase for /dev/md100: 

# ls /dev/mapper/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     220 Nov 12 12:38 .
drwxr-xr-x. 23 root root    4.6K Nov 12 12:38 ..
crw-------.  1 root root 10, 236 Aug 23 21:55 control
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       7 Nov 12 12:38 md100 -> ../dm-7

# fdisk -luc /dev/md100
Disk /dev/md100: 4.6 TiB, 5000845787136 bytes, 1220909616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 268431360 bytes

# fdisk -luc /dev/dm-7
Disk /dev/dm-7: 4.6 TiB, 5000577355776 bytes, 1220844081 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 268431360 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x867f8d2b

Device                   Boot     Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/md100-part1           65535 1220844080 1220778546  4.6T  5 Extended
/dev/mapper/md100-part5          131070  268562429  268431360 1024G 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/md100-part6       268627965  334162964   65535000  250G 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/md100-part7       334228500  399763499   65535000  250G 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/md100-part8       399829035  465364034   65535000  250G 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/md100-part9       465429570  530964569   65535000  250G 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/md100-part10      531030105  596565104   65535000  250G 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/md100-part11      596630640  662165639   65535000  250G 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/md100-part12      662231175  727766174   65535000  250G 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/md100-part13      727831710  793366709   65535000  250G 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/md100-part14      793432245 1220844080  427411836  1.6T 83 Linux
```

There's nothing under `/dev/**` corresponding to any of the partitions, so I don't know how to mount them.  I don't want to just start over, because back when I started this I *may* have put something in those partitions that I don't want to arbitrarily trash.

What am I missing in terms of accessing those partitions and mounting them?

Thanks!

Comment: Your probably not missing anything.  It sounds like something happened to the partition table.  Data recovery is made more difficult with full disk encryption

Comment: Thanks..  Are you suggesting that encrypting each partition separately on the RAID1 device is safer/better?  Is there any way to get those partitions from `dm-7` to mountable device files?

Comment: I am saying continuous backups should be done when full disk encryption is used.  Those backups can also be encrypted obviously.

Comment: Noted.  But before I reconfigure this setup, I want to mount those partitions-at-one-remove to ensure there's nothing there I want to keep.  They're somehow hidden behind the `device-mapper` insertion, so how can I 'export' the partition table to someplace at which they become mountable?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried kpartx -a /dev/mapper/md100? This may create the partition devices for you in /dev/mapper.